# Is 'var' a reserved word in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net

While running the following code below, I received the following error:

*Type 'var' is not defined.*

Is 'var' a reserved word in VB.NET?

If not, why am I getting this error and how do I resolve it?

```
<WebMethod()> _
Public Shared Function SaveData(empdata As String) As String
    Dim serializeData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of List(Of Employee))(empdata)
    Using con = New SqlConnection(Constr)
        For Each data As var In serializeData
            Using cmd = New SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Employees VALUES(@Fname, @Lname,@Email,@CreatedDate)")

                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Fname", data.FName)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Lname", data.LName)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", data.EmailId)
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CreatedDate", DateTime.Now)
                cmd.Connection = con
                If con.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
                    con.Open()
                End If
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
                con.Close()
            End Using
        Next
    End Using
    Return Nothing
End Function
```

'Updated:

```
    function getAllEmpData() {
        var data = [];
        $('tr.data-contact-person').each(function () {
            var firstName = $(this).find('.spousename01').val();
            var lastName = $(this).find('.spouseaddress01').val();
            var emailId = $(this).find('.spouseincome01').val();
            var alldata = {
                'FName': firstName,
                'LName': lastName,
                'EmailId': emailId
            }
            data.push(alldata);
        });
        console.log(data);
        return data;
    }

    $("#btnSubmit").click(function () {
        var data = JSON.stringify(getAllEmpData());
        //console.log(data);
        $.ajax({
            url: 'closures.aspx/SaveData',
            type: 'POST',
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            data: JSON.stringify({ 'empdata': data }),
            success: function () {
                alert("Data Added Successfully");
            },
            error: function () {
                alert("Error while inserting data");
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: Not it is not a reserved word, but it is not a `Type` as the message and way you are using it requires.  `For each Item as Employee In serializeData` is probably what you want or `For Each emp In serializeData`  (BTW that is DEserialized data)

Comment: No, but you are using it like a type. After a `As` you are supposed to use a Type.

Comment: Unrelated. It doesn't make a lot of sense to open/close the connection at each loop (and the same is true for the parameters collection, you could define them outside the loop and change just the value inside the loop)

Comment: Btw: [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ksh7h19t(v=vs.90).aspx) is a list of VB keywords (probably not complete but still pretty useful).

Comment: opening and closing the DB connection for every command, as you're doing, is very inefficient. Open the connection outside the loop first, and close it after the loop finishes.

Comment: Yes that should gag on the second item when you try to add a second `@Fname` parameter

Comment: This is weird. I am using Json object to submit data to the database.

That's where var came in. Am I doing this incorrectly?

Please see updated info at top.

Comment: If you want it to infer the type automatically, just leave `as` part away:
`For Each data In serializeData`

Comment: as the first commenter said you can just do `For Each data As Employee In serializeData`. After all, in the `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject` you already told it to convert the data into a list of `Employee`, so you already know the type. There's really no need to worry about using an anonymous object here or anything. And `var` is only meaningful is JavaScript and C#, it has no meaning in VB.NET, but neither is it a defined type in the way you've used it.

Comment: You can use even reserved words for your variables. Put it in brackets. Dim [Dim] = "Dim"